# Even when mocking with Mockito I am getting Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock a call to a method of a different service in Test code. However, the code where the actually call is made, for some reason instead of having my mocked value, it is null so my test fails with a Null Pointer Exception.

Here is a section of code of actual function. This code renews a jobTimeout for long running queries in a sepearate thread

```
CompanionTask.java 
public void run()
{ 
 try
 { 
    String jobLeaseTimeoutString = header.get(JOB_LEASE_TIMEOUT).get(0)
    Instant jobLeaseTimeout = Instant.parse(jobLeaseTimeoutString)
   if (jobLeaseTime != null)
   {
     if (isJobLeaseExpiring(jobLeaseTimeout))
     {
      ResponseEntity<ReportJob> reply = ctx.getReportingManagerClient().refreshReportJobLease(ctx.getJob().getId());
      jobLeaseTimeoutString = reply.getHeaders().get(JOB_LEASE_TIMEOUT).get(0);
    }
    else
    {
      sleep();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the Test where I mocked the call to ReportManagerClient but it is showing up as NULL when debugging

```
CompanionTaskTest.java
@MockBean
protected ReportingManagerIntegration reportingManagerClient;
@MockBean
protected NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@Test
public void testCompanionTask() 
{
  ReportJob reportJob = generateReportJob();
  QueryContext ctx = QueryContext.builder()
          .jdbc(jdbcTemplate)
          .busy(new AtomicInteger())
          .reportingManagerClient(reportingManagerClient)
          .job(reportJob)
          .build();

  ReportJob reportJobMock = ReportJob.builder()
         .createdAt(Instant.now())
         .expiresAt(Instant.now().plusSeconds(60)
         .build();

  Instant leaseRenewTimeout = Instant.now().plusSeconds(10);
  ResponseEntity responseEntity = ResonseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header(JOB_LEASE_TIMEOUT, leaseTimeout.toString())
        .body(reportJobMock);

 Instant leaseRenewTimeout = Instant.now(0.plusSeconds(300);
 ResponseEntity<ReportJob> responseReportJob = ResponseEntity.ok()
       .contentTyoe(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       .header(JOB_LEASE_TIMEOUT, leaseTimeout.toString())
       .body(reportJobMock);
   when(ctx.getReportingManagerClient().refreshReportJobLease(anyString())).thenReturn(responseReportJob);

when(reportingManagerClient.refreshReportJobLease(anyString())).thenReturn(responseReportJob);
CompanionTask task = new CompanionTask(ctx, responseEntity.getHeaders());
something
task.run();
```

x

My work has stackvoerflow blocked , so I had to manually write all this code. Sorry for any typo I might have overlooked.
So even though I have these two lines
when(ctx.getReportingManagerClient().refreshReportJobLease(anyString())).thenReturn(responseReportJob);
when(reportingManagerClient.refreshReportJobLease(anyString())).thenReturn(responseReportJob);

when the control is going to
ResponseEntity reply = ctx.getReportingManagerClient().refreshReportJobLease(ctx.getJob().getId());
reply is NULL and that is giving me a NullPointerException.

Comment: What annotations are applied to your test? Why do you mix beans and mockito?

Comment: `anyString()` does _not_ match `null`. What is the value of `ctx.getJob().getId()` when your method is executed?

Comment: @Test annotation is applied to my test

Comment: @knittl you are absolutely right. My ctx.getJob().getId() was null. Oh my god, I spent so much time on this. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

ArgumentMatchers such as `Mockito.anyString()` do *not* match `null`. Make sure your code is not passing null (and thus the stubbed method is not matched). If your stub needs to handle nulls use `any()` (matches anything, including null) or `nullable(String.class)` (matches any string *and* nulls).